# SQLite: How to select a column with whitespace without use it?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-injection

So, I'm trying to do a SQL injection in a ctf application that removes all whitespace in form parameters, so I can't use it. To perform my query I used /**/ to insert whitespace and I could perform many queries using something like:

`1'/**/UNION/**/SELECT/**/column/**/FROM/**/table;--`

I'm injecting SQL in a SELECT query.

Now I have a problem: The column name that I need has one whitespace, something like: `my column`. So my query would be like:

`1'/**/UNION/**/SELECT/**/"my column"/**/FROM/**/table;--`

But I need to remove this whitespace. I tried to use hex encoding: `SELECT/**/X'hex_ecoding'/**/...` but it always return the same blob structure. Is there any way to do this in SQLite?

Comment: SQL uses double quotes to quote identifiers with special characters. `"my column"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sql select column via column number/index/position instead of column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34717530/sql-select-column-via-column-number-index-position-instead-of-column-name)

Comment: @Shawn yes but I can't use whitespace in my query

Comment: @Yunnosch It works in a single query but I couldn't execute it with an UNION query (I use UNION because I'm injecting in a SELECT query). Do you know how can I use UNION with WITH query?

Comment: If you can do it for a simple query but fail to do it use a union, then please show the simple query code here (as part of a [mre], please read the info provided for the sqlite tag you used) and ask more specifically about how to do that with a union. As long as nobody answered to this simpler question, you can still edit it to change/widen the focus of your question.

Comment: @Yunnosch I've just updated my question putting the exact code

Comment: Please provide a MRE to base the answer on and allow testing. Define a desired output.

Comment: @Yunnosch I don't know how to do this... I've provided all the info that I have. I don't have the source code. All that I know is that in the code the query is like `'SELECT column FROM table WHERE id=' + idvar` that allows SQL injection. I'm providing a parameter `1' UNION SELECT column_with_whitespace FROM table2`. This parameter is the `id` that will be inserted in the query string. I can't use withspaces because the application remove them. So basically, I only have the control of the second SELECT query, I couldn't use WITH with UNION query.

Comment: Did you read the info on "Sqlite" as provided by the tag you used? It explains how to make a useful MRE. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info Reading that info on the tags you use with questions is really helpful. Sometimes the contained FAQs are so good that they answer questions.

Comment: Please also show the query you are trying to inject into, the result it is supposed to produce (from a correct sample input) and the result you are trying to produce with an injectious input.